# PowerShell: return the number of instances find in a file for a search pattern

Tags: powershell

I have a text file with the following contents:

```
something
another something
stuff
more stuff
```

Using PowerShell, I have a script that searches for the pattern "something".  This pattern will appear at most once per line on the file.  I am trying to determine the number of times that this search pattern was found in the file (i.e., the number of lines that contain this pattern).  I am using the following script:

```
$something_list = Select-String -Path $some_path -Pattern "something" | Select-Object Line
```

I then run the following command to get the number of elements in the Line property:

```
$n = $something_list.Length - 1
```

The problem I'm having is that this works if there are 2+ instances of "something" in the file.  If there is only 1 instance of "something" in the file, $something_list.Length is meaningless, since Length can't be referenced for Line objects with only 1 element in them.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [Measure-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113349) cmdlet to select the count:

```
Select-String -Path $some_path -Pattern "something" | Measure-Object  | select -expand count
```

Comment: I think it should be select count -ExpandProperty Count.

Comment: Or just `... | Select -Exp Count` or  `... | Foreach count`